# How to declare a variable in to a string

Tags: powershell

I have this:

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments')
```

but I need to declare the rest of the path:

```
\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SharePointOnline.CSOM\0.1.0\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
```

How can I do that?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by 'declare', when you say 'declare the rest of the path'.

Comment: save the two into $Vars and then use `Join-Path` to join them. the cmdlet is aware of path delimiters, so there no need to add a `\` - or to worry about too- many/too-few of them. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few ways to do this
You can put the object into a variable by declaring a variable $VariableName

```
$Test = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments')

"$Test\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SharePointOnline.CSOM\0.1.0\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
```

Or

Using **$()** this allows you to declare the output of commands as a variable

```
"$([Environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments'))\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SharePointOnline.CSOM\0.1.0\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
```